# Uncaught ReferenceError: GEvent is not defined after migrating to google map api v3

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-maps-api

I have managed to change the needed things, but I get the error from the title in the console, and I cannot figure it out what else needs to be done. any ideas? This is my code(if you paste it and run it, it will show):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/api/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/dojo/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
    </script>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/gmaps/?v=1.6" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.require("esri.map");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        dojo.require("esri.dijit.Legend");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("esri.dijit.BasemapGallery");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("dijit.Menu");

        var layer, map, visible = [], toolbar, symbol, geomTask, gmap;

        function init(mapServer) {
            var centerat = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
            var options = {
                center: centerat,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
            var dynamicMap = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.DynamicMapServiceLayer(mapServer, null, 0.75, dynmapcallback);
        }

        function dynmapcallback(mapservicelayer) {
            gmap.addOverlay(mapservicelayer);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainWindow"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
    data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">


    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Layers', selected:true">
                <select id="mapServers">
                    <option value="">Please select a MapServer</option>
                    <option 

value="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer">Census</option>
                    <option 

value="http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/BloomfieldHillsMichigan/Parcels/MapServer">Bloomfield 

Parcels</option>
                </select>
                <span id="layer_list"></span>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#mapServers').on('change', function (e) {
        var selectedMap = $("option:selected", this);

        if (this.value != "")
            init(this.value);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to use Arcgis Extension for Google Maps API version 1.6 (http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/gmaps/help/topics/apiref.htm) with Google Maps API version 3. You should also update the ArcGIS Server extension to the new version: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arcgislink/docs/examples.html.